# Change Submenu Visibility onClick -- getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css

Thanks for checking out my question! I'm trying to change visibility of a submenu using getElementsByClassName.  The Javascript needs to detect a click then open the submenu.  Then close button is clicked on it will trigger a function to close the submenu / panel. I just need help with the getElementsByClassName / click to open portion really, but anything else would be great!

HTML

```
      <div id="ux-nav" class="nav-start">
                <div class="wrap cf">
                    <nav role="navigation">
                        <ul id="menu-start" class="nav secondary-nav cf">
                            <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-123">
                                <a href="https://websitename.com" aria-current="page">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-12">
                                <a href="#">parent</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11">
                                        <a href="https://website.com/">sub 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12">
                                        <a href="https://website.com/">sub 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="closePanel()">X</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                 </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-has-children')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    
       setAttribute.visibilty:visible;
});
```

CSS

```
ul.sub-menu { 
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
 transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an element to set the attribute, `event.target` will give you clicked element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-has-children')[0].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    
       event.target.setAttribute('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an item on which you can set your attribute and the parameter are in ().

```
thist.setAttribute('visibilty', 'visible');
```

Try it.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-has-children')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
       thist.setAttribute('visibilty', 'visible');
});
```

```css
ul.sub-menu { 
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
 transition: opacity 500ms, visibility 500ms;
    }
```

```html
      <div id="ux-nav" class="nav-start">
                <div class="wrap cf">
                    <nav role="navigation">
                        <ul id="menu-start" class="nav secondary-nav cf">
                            <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item menu-item-123">
                                <a href="https://websitename.com" aria-current="page">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-12">
                                <a href="#">parent</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-11">
                                        <a href="https://website.com/">sub 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-12">
                                        <a href="https://website.com/">sub 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="closePanel()">X</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                 </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```